Asymptotically equivalent real sequences
I came across a definition: Let $(x_{n}),(y_{n})$ be two real sequences. They are asymptotically equivalent if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}=1$.
My intuition is as follows: Two sequences are asymptotically equivalent if their limit is the same and they behave similarly (in terms of increasing/ decreasing). Is it correct?
Can anyone please give more clarity, idea and motivation behind this definition and what is the intuitive meaning behind the definition.

You should rather think about this as a weakening of their limits being the same. If both sequences converge to non-zero limits, then this is equivalent to the limits coinciding. Whether they increase or decrease doesn't matter. However, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ can be equal to one even if neither of the limits $\lim_n x_n$ or $\lim_n y_n$ exist. If they both go to zero, then you should think of this as them going to zero "approximately at the same rate".

So I believe there are three situations here: 1) Both limit exist (non zero). 2) Both limit doesn't exist (In this case how to make sense of the definition?) 3) Both limit exist and is zero (Intuitively I understand rate, but mathematically how to make it precise?), are other situations impossible? Like one limit exist and other doesn't etc.

I am unsure what you are asking now. The definition you have presented of asymptotic equivalence is mathematically precise. There is no issue with the definition of neither of the limits exist. The limit on the quotient may still exist, and may still be equal to one. Take for example any sequence without a limit and let both $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ be that sequence. The sequence of quotients is constantly equal to 1 and so converges trivially.

If the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$ exists, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ also exists, since the  $x_n = y_n \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ (apply product rule for limits). If $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$ exists by a similar reason as above. So both limits have to exist, if one of the limits exists.
